# Having an VStack as a property in a Struct

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

I need to have a `VStack` as a property in a struct like this

```
struct Str
{ 
  let view: VStack
  ....
}
```

The compiler says:
"Reference to generic type 'VStack' requires arguments in <...>
Insert '<<#Content: View#>>'
"

Xcodes "fix" produces:

```
struct Str
{
  let view: VStack<Content: View>
  ...
}
```

But the compiler still complains:
"Expected '>' to complete generic argument list"

Is it allowed to have a VStack in a struct?

Comment: Can you show what you want to do with the `view`? I feel like this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: I will pass the struct as parameter to another view.
That view will use the property view in its body

Comment: Why not make `Str` a `View` itself then?

Comment: Are you trying to assign different _kinds_ of `VStack` to `view`? For example, a `VStack` with a bunch of `Text`, and a `VStack` with a bunch of `Button` etc. That's not possible. Hence, I'm asking "why are you doing this in the first place?"

Comment: passing e.g. a Button or a VStack as a parameter to my View to use it in it's content leads to the same error message. 
What's wrong with e.g. an VStack a s parameter?

Comment: no all the same kind of VStacks.
These shall be used as label for a Button in the content of the view

Comment: "What's wrong with e.g. an VStack a s parameter?" It's wrong because `VStack` is generic, and you need to supply generic types. `Button` is also generic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208283/discussion-between-sweeper-and-mica).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have discovered is that `VStack` is not really a type. We can more accurately describe it as a “type constructor”. It is declared like this:

```
struct VStack<Content> where Content : View {
    ...
}
```

You give it some other type as its `Content` argument, and it gives you a type. You give it the type `Text` and you get back the type `VStack<Text>`. You give it the type `Image` and you get back the type `VStack<Image>`. The types you get back are different types! A object of type `VStack<Text>` is **not** an object of type `VStack<Image>`.

So you just need to know what type to pass as the argument, right? Well, the problem is that **lots** of SwiftUI “types” are actually generic type constructors. So the type gets complex. Here's an example from an app I'm working on:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        scene
        if store.model.latestError != nil {
            Divider()
            ErrorView(store: errorStore)
                .padding(20)
        }
    } //
        .frame(width: 450)
}
```

What's the type of `body`? I can print it at runtime to find out:

```
print(type(of: AppView(store: store).body))
```

The output is

```
ModifiedContent<VStack<TupleView<(AnyView, Optional<TupleView<(Divider, ModifiedContent<ErrorView, _PaddingLayout>)>>)>>, _FrameLayout>
```

Notice that the type of the object returned by `body` exposes lots of details about `body`'s implementation. For example, because the `ErrorView` has a `padding` modifier, the `body` object's type includes `ModifiedContent<ErrorView, _PaddingLayout>`. I can change the padding amount from 20 to 30 without changing the type. But if I remove the `padding` modifier entirely, it changes the type (by changing `ModifiedContent<ErrorView, _PaddingLayout>` to just `ErrorView`).

So how do you solve this? One way is to use `AnyView`:

```
struct Str {
    let view: AnyView
    ...
}

let str = Str(view: AnyView(VStack {
    ...
}))
```

Note that sometimes you will hear advice that you should avoid `AnyView`. Here's [Joe Groff](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/1136068308543856640) explaining why:

> You can use the AnyView wrapper to explicitly wrap up types where they can dynamically change.
>
> However, the animation system will have an easier time if you can push this down the view graph as far as possible. You could have one Layout type that takes `.portrait`/`.landscape`, apply rotation, translation, etc. differently in response, and then the transition can animate